# IPS panel color acuracy web design

Tags: colors

I design websites on a fairly nice IPS panel screen. My problem is that everything looks so marvelous on the IPS panel and then I go and look at a standard TFT screen and my coloring is really dull and boring. How can I make my designs work with both monitors? I can't seem to find any information on the internet which is strange.

Comment: Try adjusting the settings of your other monitor. The "designs" you do have standard colors in them, it just depends on how they are displayed by the medium in which you are viewing them.

Comment: It's like testing software on other platforms. Get a cheap LCD and check your page on both. So you can be sure, that your webpage looks perfect.

Comment: IPS with LED has its own issues too , Agrees with Shiki, the only way to design for the customers, is to display like the customers, any one of them.  For me color seems to also be a matter of triggering, or over triggering the eye receptors and brain reponse, Live with a monitor bleeding in blue, and the other ones look yellow. Have high saturations, and normal saturations look bland and lifeless. The photo receptors stop firing as strong, and brain evens stuff out. Did you ever live under the other panel type and figure that everything looked good then too?

Answer (score 1):

there is a big problem with colors settings among various LCD panels. I think that commonly sold cheap LCD panels have different colors from those IPS ones. So you can use some laptop or cheap LCD and adjust your colors to be enough bright and contrast on it and then check it on your IPS whether it is not too bright and unpleasant for your eyes.  No need for any advanced equipment as this is not for printing.